# Most elegant way to split a sequence into individual steps in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, split, chunks

Say I have a list from 0 to 9:

```
lst = list(range(10))
```

I want to split it into individual steps of 2. I managed to write the following working code:

```
res = [[] for _ in range(len(lst) - 1)]
for i, x in enumerate(lst):
    if i < len(lst) - 1:
        res[i].append(x)
    if i > 0:
        res[i-1].append(x)

>>> print(res)
[[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7], [7, 8], [8, 9]]
```

But I feel like there should be more elegant way to code this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a list of tuples:

```
>>> list(zip(lst,lst[1:]))
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9)]
```

For a list of lists:

```
>>> list(map(list, zip(lst,lst[1:])))
[[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7], [7, 8], [8, 9]]
```

Comment: @AlainT. My comment was directed at a previous version that used `zip(lst[:-1],lst[1:])`. Now this is common and fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can generalize to `n` steps:

```
def steps(lst, n=2):
    return [[*x] for x in zip(*(lst[i:] for i in range(n)))]

steps(range(10), 2)
# [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7], [7, 8], [8, 9]]
steps(range(10), 3)
# [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Python 3.10 now has [`pairwise()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise).  The items will be tuples.

```py
>>> list(itertools.pairwise(range(10)))
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use zip function along with list comprehension.

```
>>> lst = list(range(10))
>>> [list(elm) for elm in zip(lst, lst[1:])]
[[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7], [7, 8], [8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution ​without `zip`, just using indexes, `range`, `len` and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
lst = list(range(10))
res = [ [lst[i], lst[i+1]] for i in range(len(lst) - 1)]
print(res)
# [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7], [7, 8], [8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid `zip` completely and just use list comprehension to create the sliding window.

```
[lst[i: i + 2] for i in range(0, len(lst) - 1)]
>> [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7], [7, 8], [8, 9]]
```